# How to include resources in IntelliJ Gradle JavaFx project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, gradle, log4j2

I am building a JavaFx project in IntelliJ using the Gradle project structure and a JavaFx Gradle plugin:

[Gradle JavaFx Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle/overview)

I was wondering how to include resource files on the classpath.  Specifically, I am currently trying to define a log4j2 configuration JSON file that log4j2 will load at runtime.  I am currently getting the following message when I run my application:

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found.  Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console.

I currently have the log4j2.json file located in src/main/resources/log4j2.json

I am able to load FXML files using `getClass().getResources().load(...)` from my `Application` class, so it appears that files within the "resources" directory are being packaged, but it seems they are not accessible via the classpath that log4j2 is using to load a configuration file.

Any idea what I need to do to have log4j2.json and other similar files available to the source code with a JavaFx project using the Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue wasn't with IntelliJ, Gradle, or JavaFx, it was with Log4j2.  Apparently Jackson is a dependency for processing the JSON file, even though the Log4j2 Gradle documentation didn't bother to mention that.

The solution came from [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435990/log4j-2-json-configuration).

Comment: The log4j2 manual > Configuration > JSON Syntax mentions the dependency on Jackson: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#JSON . Also the Components > Implementation page: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/index.html . It is hard to cover all the bases.