# How to configure log4j 2 in JSON configuraion for springframework?

Tags: json, xml, spring, log4j2

I want to debug springframework, To know what is happening while routing request in Restcontroller. 
I have defined **JSON** configuration like below but that is not working for me.

```
 {
    "configuration": {
        "appenders": {
            "Console": {
                "name": "consoleAppender",
                "target":"SYSTEM_OUT",
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p [%c{1}:%t]:%L - %m%n"
                }
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "root": {
                "level": "info",
                "appender-ref": [{ "ref": "consoleAppender" }]
            },
            "logger":[{
                "name":"org.springframework", 
                "level": "debug",
                "appender-ref": [{ "ref": "consoleAppender" }]
            }]
        }
    }
```

}

Let me know, if i am doing wrong here.
And another question regarding , **what is right way to configure log4j using JSON or XML ?**

Comment: You can use either JSON or XML. I would suggest looking at the unit tests. There are many sample configuration files. As for it not working, 1. Use appenderRef instead of appender-ref. 2. You don't need the '[' or ']" on the references since there is only a single ref.

Comment: apparently, there are issues for json configuration attempting to parse using the xml dom parsers, if you haven't included other jackson-xxx dependencies, which is completely unmentioned in the log4j documentation. I don't know what exactly isn't working for you, but thought I'd mention this in case somebody else hits it. See the answer here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435990/log4j-2-json-configuration

Answer (score 1):

The below configuration is using for log4j framework. Its describe on XML .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
        <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL0"/>
        <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="false"/>
        <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [WhereRU][%t|%c{1}] %L %M %m\n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SERVER_DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
        <param name="File" value="/var/log/testing/testing-debug"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [WhereRU][%t|%c{1}] %L %M %m\n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SERVER_ERROR" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
        <param name="File" value="/var/log/testing/testing-error"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [WhereRU][%t|%c{1}] %L %M %m\n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [WhereRU][%t|%c{1}] %L %M %m\n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.testing" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
         <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
         <appender-ref ref="SERVER_DEBUG"/>
         <appender-ref ref="SERVER_ERROR"/>
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
         <appender-ref ref="SERVER_ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
         <appender-ref ref="SERVER_ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.integration">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.integration.samples">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Everything else to catalina.out -->
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SERVER_DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="SERVER_ERROR" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Hopes this stuff worked on your problem.

Comment: Whatever you shared  seem to be log4j 1.x configuration. I need log4j 2.x configuration with json and xml.                                                   here is migration link of log4j 2 https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html