# Log4j2 not working with json config file

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, log4j, kotlin

It seems like log4j is trying to parse .json config file by XML parser, but why?

I set log4j config file by command line argument:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/log4j2.json
```

file content:

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "appenders": {
            "Console": {
                "name": "Console",
                "target": "SYSTEM_OUT",
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%date %thread %logger %message"
                }
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "root": {
                "level": "debug",
                "appender-ref": {
                    "ref": "Console"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get:

```
[Fatal Error] log4j2.json:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing D:\Dev\HDelphiCrawler\src\log4j2.json org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///D:/Dev/HDelphiCrawler/src/log4j2.json; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:410)
    ....and so on...
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration
```

Jars in my lib folder:

- hamcrest-junit-2.0.0.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar
- jackson-core-2.6.1.jar
- jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar
- java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar
- junit-4.12.jar
- kotlin-reflect.jar
- kotlin-runtime-sources.jar
- kotlin-runtime.jar
- log4j-api-2.3.jar
- log4j-core-2.3.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.3.jar

Comment: I would suggest adding -Dlog4j2.StatusLogger.level=DEBUG. It should print some debugging messages that might help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the system property `log4j.configurationFactory`:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFactory=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.json.JsonConfigurationFactory
```

Comment: FYI: log4j2 stil WON"T work without `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` in dependencies.

Comment: @expert Maybe, but as far as I see, the question states that jackson-databind is in the lib folder, so this dependency is not the question.

Answer (score 8):

Even though there is already an accepted answer I'll post my solution too. Maybe this helps someone else in the future...

The reason why it didn't work for me was that I didn't have the `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` library available. After I added

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.7'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.2'
```

to my `build.gradle` file everything worked fine.