# Log4j2 not working with json config file even if configured properly

Tags: java, json, log4j2

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269559/log4j2-not-working-with-json-config-file/32269917#32269917?newreg=3ef840ea49fc4888be701dfc2b93dda5) question but the solution proposed there doesn't work for me and I cannot yet comment.

The issue is explained in the title itself: Log4j2 is not working with `.json` config file even if configured properly with `log4j.configurationFactory=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.json.JsonConfigurationFactory` in `log4j2.component.properties` file.

The full error stack trace is:

```
[Fatal Error] log4j2.json:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing /Users/sm/cdss-scala/risk-stratification/src/main/resources/log4j2.json
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///Users/sm/cdss-scala/risk-stratification/src/main/resources/log4j2.json; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:491)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:265)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:613)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logger$.apply(Logger.scala:39)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging$class.$init$(Logging.scala:28)
    at eu.connecare.cdss.hadrian.HadrianService$.<init>(HadrianService.scala:11)
    at eu.connecare.cdss.hadrian.HadrianService$.<clinit>(HadrianService.scala)
    at eu.connecare.cdss.hadrian.HadrianService.runEngine(HadrianService.scala)
    at eu.connecare.cdss.hadrian.HadrianLaunchable.main(HadrianLaunchable.java:6)
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4j2 not working with json config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269559/log4j2-not-working-with-json-config-file)

Comment: you should show your json config, otherwise no one will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

It's no use to show your json config, as my experience, something wrong of BOM with your json file. Try to add/remove the BOM to/from your json file.

Waht's BOM and how to remove the BOM, see here: 
[Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)